# AAD Application Client Secret

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to generate AAD client secret for an app registration with powershell or Rest API? The intend is to use in an automation script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the 
[`New-AzureRmADAppCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadappcredential?view=azurermps-6.6.0)
 cmdlet.

**Example:**

```
PS C:\> $SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "secret" -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\> New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ObjectId <YOUR APP ID> -Password $SecureStringPassword
```

Comment: While we generate in the portal it auto-generate the Key. Can we give any string as secret while generating through powershell?

Comment: Yes, the key is what you put in the `-String` variable in the first line - in this case *secret*